# Starting x11vnc as a non-root user

Tags: linux, permissions, x11vnc

I'm using a customized Linux distribution generated via buildroot. I use `x11vnc` for remote access, always logging in with `root`. But now, I need to enable an user without root privileges to start `x11vnc`, even though the X server was started by `root`.

In my research, I came across numerous methods for doing so, but all of them using resources our customized distribution doesn't currently have, such as `xauth` or `xhost`.

Is there any simple way to enable `x11vnc` for non-root users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for a non-root user to start `x11vnc` without having to install or configure anything else. It's perhaps not the *cleanest* way to do it, but it works.

I created a script that runs during startup:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd  /home/amorimph/
while true; do
    if [ -e startVNC ]
    then
        x11vnc -display :0
        rm startVNC
    fi
done
```

It checks the user's directory for the existence of the 'startVNC' file. Then, when I log in as this non-root user, a `touch startVNC` starts `x11vnc` and the file is removed after the process exits.